# Instant vector for every tag value used in aggregation operator

Tags: prometheus, promql

Here is my promql query:

```
sum by(package_type) (Havoc_FlowTime_Count{status=~"SUCCEEDED"})
```

There are time series for **package_type** that do not have any values with status tag set as  "SUCCEEDED". As a result of it that there are no instant vectors for aforementioned **package_type** labels included in the result. Is there a way to include all of them with '0' values set to the ones that are missed now?